Is reputation harder to earn in 2024?
I recall seeing on another, non SE website:

Most reputation that will ever been earned on this website has already been earned. For new users, it's a slog to the top.

That is, older users with a few posts have hundreds of thousands of reputation points, while newer active users are unable to earn that sort of reputation, despite posting many more questions and answers.
If this is true, it means reputation no longer accurately reflects the amount of value added to the site.
To what extent is this true? What can be done to solve this problem?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122323/is-it-more-difficult-to-earn-reputation-on-so-than-couple-of-years-ago

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318001/over-time-on-stack-overflow-it-is-harder-to-earn-a-great-deal-of-reputation-w

I wonder if link #1 is a duplicate. It's fairly similar, but it is specific to SO.

I don't think this is a dupe, just related; that one is 12 years old. In any case, imo, it is much harder these days to gain reps, in general, on any of network sites due to number of reasons, such as reduced traffic, lower quality of questions, less things to ask about, etc.

"it means reputation no longer accurately reflects the amount of value added to the site." Why not? I think this doesn't really follow from the statements before. Maybe add more details there.

Have any suggestions from that post been implemented since it was posted almost 2 years ago?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution is this not self-evident? The number of voters has collapsed so equivalent contributions get less rep.

Yes the situation is real, no there’s nothing to be done, sites dying/dead and beyond saving. The company alienated/attacked/slandered/threatened/disrespected/ignored a critical mass of contributors, and then ChatGPT crushed their remaining market share as they continued to ignore their user experience, as they have since around when Jeff left and Joel was alone in charge. It’s so so so far beyond the point of no return.

You really don’t have to slog to the top. I’ve got the association bonus for 100 rep on each site and it barely makes a difference compared to the sites where I am in the 500 rep range, or 2k+, or 30k+. Those are still very far away from the rep range of top users.

@Jeremy "The number of voters has collapsed so equivalent contributions get less rep." The number of contributions has also collapsed. What you mean is that the number of votes per contribution and per time is decreasing and that may be the case but would require a bit more statistics to be presented. Or it could be that contributions aren't equivalent, the useful questions have been asked already and new contributions are less equivalent. Just check all this to have bit more solid base. Or give some examples.

And finally one could ask oneself if it's really the purpose of rep to do all this. It's unicorn points anyway. It's just a number that is displayed for some reason. The only critical things is that privileges are tied to that number. Now if you would argue that new contributors don't earn privileges anymore and therefore can't participate anymore and maybe also show some statistics from SEDE about it, that would be more serious in my eyes.

The duplicate target is a bit outdated and very general and above all already not monitored by staff anymore. This questions seems to be more localized and more interested in actual data. Not sure if I would want to post an answer to this question there.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution yet OP accepted it ¯\(ツ)/¯

Closely related is also the discussion about how big an exchange needs to be to remain healthy. If no new curators (people with privileges taking care of content) arise a slow starvation process will follow.

I don't know, VLAZ. At the time my question was getting plenty of downvotes so I assumed the community thought it to be a dupe. In hindsight, I don't think it's a dupe. I have voted to reopen.

Now the duplicate target is supposed to be from 2012. But the situation in 2012 was completely opposite with growing activity instead of falling activity like now. For a question asking about today, 2012 is almost ancient.

I looked at the closing history - the dupe I accepted was a different one to the one from 2012.

@stickynotememo The system allows for people to select different targets and in the end takes the target with the highest votes (above a threshold?). It may result in unreliable dupe targets.

Not really. The average number of upvotes per post cast within the first week of that post's existence is 1.2. In 2015, it was 1.3. It's been virtually unchanged for the last decade. Way back in the early days - like 2009 or 2010, it was a bit higher: 1.5 to 2.0. But that's super early and doesn't account for most of the content on the site today.
Ok, I'll admit that's not quite the whole truth. Probably finding good questions to answer has gotten harder (see Laurel's answer on this post). But if you can find a post within your domain of knowledge, then on average you can expect to be upvoted at about the same rate you did years ago.
The people with lots of rep and a long post history just have a head start.
(For the curious, it's flat both for questions and for answers taken separately. It's also flat across a range of interval lengths, e.g. 30 days, 90 days, 180 days.)

Is this over all stackexchanges or SO only? Also I wonder how many of the total votes are given in the first week of the posts existence.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Querying across all network sites is a little tricky, and probably obscures the underlying dynamics between different sites. Most posts get most of the votes they'll ever get within the first week (which has always been true); only outliers continue to accrue votes, but outliers do so at different rates, and this results in some really badly behaved statistics.

But if these outliers account for a sizeable chunk of the votes I wouldn't call them outliers anymore. Maybe a different name, say "stars" for example. It might be that it got more difficult to produce "star" Q&A and average reputation gain per actively asking or answering user per year dropped then. But it's good to hear that relative voting activity more or less remains constant. Someone is at least still reading new contributions and voting on them.

True, @NoData, but at that point the hypothesis is more subtle. Not that voting has fallen off a cliff, but rather that voting on new posts is more concentrated than voting on new posts used to be. Still possible to test but more complex. Might be true tho. This doesn't disprove it

As a one word answer, I would say yes, but it's not as hopeless as it seems. The specifics, of course, can vary considerably across sites.
It's true that the easiest and most broadly relevant questions on a topic are usually asked, generously upvoted, and answered early in a site's life (or at least before you personally got there). Usually the answers are stellar, refined over the course of years, and have accumulated a lot of upvotes over time too. Time is also important when looking at user rep scores since reputation per day is capped, so 1000 upvotes for a person spread over a year is worth a lot more than the same number in a day (which is only worth 200 points of rep).
Many sites, however, have at least one type of evergreen question that doesn't get harder to ask over time:

Questions about current events, new media/publications, recent advancements, or similar. (In the same way, all of this can provide content for new answers to existing questions.)
Questions highly specific to the person who asked, like identification questions, word/phrasing questions, or review questions. (There are a few rare sites, like Code Review, that mostly or entirely host this type of question.)

New questions are the best opportunity for new answers, and those answers tend to get more reputation than new answers to old questions due to how question lists work. When the timing is exactly right and with the right execution, not only can a new question (and its answers) get a lot of upvotes from site locals but also people across the network if it becomes a Hot Network Question (HNQ). (The bias towards new questions in both of these cases doesn't make much sense, and I'd support changing it somehow.)
There are also some other factors that affect reputation gain:

How active voters are. Stack Overflow has seen a decline in views and votes, and many other sites have followed suit, either because they're affected by the same issues (e.g., AI alternatives to Q&A) or because significant traffic was coming through the HNQ list or in some cases for unrelated reasons. For example, any site related to elections likely follows a cyclical pattern. In some cases, the decrease in traffic spirals and there's no easy way to reverse or even stanch that pattern.
The rules of the site. The trend is usually that rules are tightened and standards are raised, limiting the viability of new questions that might have been fine or even wildly successful before. Even existing questions that only align with the old rules may be downvoted, and sometimes even locked or deleted (though any significant rep gain is usually retained). On the other hand, in rare cases are the rules loosened, or do the standards become more inclusive, but it does happen. For example, Movies & TV banned identification questions many years ago, but recently reversed that decision, reinstating some older questions while plenty of new ones have been asked. It's perhaps so much easier for a site to tighten the rules instead of loosening them because it's easy to see the negatives (e.g., low effort questions and/or answers) and hard to see positives (e.g., attracting new users who, once invested, will contribute bigger and better things), and there's inertia to overcome. The only advice I can give here is that convincing the community is usually the most important aspect, especially with moderators who follow that consensus (there's a lot fewer of them than regular users, after all).

Lastly, even though it's more difficult, there is still reputation to be gained on many sites by finding the existing gaps. What niche parts of a subject aren't covered by existing questions? What questions have wrong, incomplete, or misleading answers? Spending the time and effort to write thorough and clear Q&A even in a niche can often attract people who might otherwise not vote on Q&A about that topic.

Also worth noting that anything new tends to attract more upvotes than old stuff. Speaking for SO, established tech, observationally anyway, tends to have lower upvote rates. Unless you happen to keep up with whatever thing is new now (either in Your Favourite Tech:tm: or New Tech:tm:), it is still difficult to earn rep on at least SO. Basically, most of the low-hanging fruit is gone in established languages (which is where most new developers at least get started), and the remaining low-hanging fruit requires branching out.

There's also other edge-cases like niche tech, where the low-hanging fruit still exists, but there isn't anywhere near enough active users in the tag(s) for it to turn into rep. The complete list of edge-cases is too long to write out, but there's a considerable number of them. The "but" to the yes is, effectively,  "branch out to other things and it might get easy". As a practical example, most of my rep on SO came from the Kotlin tag, which I answered before Android adopted it as one of its two main programming languages. After that, I've been gaining a lot of passive rep because (1/2)

I got really lucky with a tech choice around 2018. Half the options for getting rep on at least SO now boil down to getting lucky with how new tech gets adapted

Another option, though not good for the site, is to ignore all moderation aspects. Being the FGITW on enough off-topic or dupe questions, on average, seems to guarantee a net positive rep gain. Caring about moderation seems to be a fantastic way to stall on rep atm

Nice answer. Is there maybe some statistics available, how much more difficult it is now? Maybe the reputation that is still be gained is only a tiny fraction of what was possible once, even with lots of time and effort to spend on high quality content.
